# Why is exit code not honored?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exit, exit-code

Suppose we write the following inside of `test_script.py`:

```
sys.exit(-992340374290374)
```

We get the following error message:

```
"[drive_letter]:\[path to python.exe]" [drive_letter]:/[path to script]

Process finished with exit code -1
```

`-1` is not `-992340374290374`. What happened?

Comment: undefined behaviour? do you really have `92340374290373` other reasons your program quits or why exactly this one?

Comment: maybe your operating system isn't handling 64-bit return codes...

Comment: Isn't an exit status supposed to be one byte?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit  - often undefined if > 127. Read the docs.

Answer (score 5):

From the [`sys.exit` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) (emphasis mine):

> Exit from Python. This is implemented by raising the SystemExit
>   exception, so cleanup actions specified by finally clauses of try
>   statements are honored, and it is possible to intercept the exit
>   attempt at an outer level.
>
> The optional argument arg can be an integer giving the exit status
>   (defaulting to zero), or another type of object. If it is an integer,
>   zero is considered “successful termination” and any nonzero value is
>   considered “abnormal termination” by shells and the like. **Most systems
>   require it to be in the range 0–127, and produce undefined results
>   otherwise.** Some systems have a convention for assigning specific
>   meanings to specific exit codes, but these are generally
>   underdeveloped; Unix programs generally use 2 for command line syntax
>   errors and 1 for all other kind of errors. If another type of object
>   is passed, None is equivalent to passing zero, and any other object is
>   printed to stderr and results in an exit code of 1. In particular,
>   sys.exit("some error message") is a quick way to exit a program when
>   an error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how your operating system handles the exit. In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) for `sys.exit` it says:

> Most systems require it to be in the range 0–127, and produce undefined results otherwise.